# Date format in the customer account dashboard

Tags: magento-1, customer-account, date, dashboard, format

The date in the customer account dashboard in my Magento store is in the format of **mm/dd/yyyy** now, that is the date in the recent orders list is in above format. I want it to be displayed in the format **dd/mm/yyyy**. I have changed the format of date in **Date & time custom options** under **catalog** in **system** -> **configuration**, but it still has not changed.

Kindly let me know How can I change the format of the date?

Comment: You have to check it by place new order.

Comment: @SHPatel I tried that, but i am still getting the date in the old format only.

Comment: Try it to clear cache if enable from admin.

Comment: @SHPatel I cleared the cache and tried too but I am still getting the date in same format.